# $M$ is free $R$-module $\iff$ $M$ has $R$-basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

We will define the free $R$-modules.

> **Definition**. Let $R$ be a ring with $1_R$ and $F$ an left $R$-module. We call $F$ **free** $R$-module, if $$F=\bigoplus_{i\in I}
>  R_i$$ where $R_i:=\langle b_i \rangle \cong _RR,\ \forall i \in I $
>   and $I$ is a set of indexes (finite or infinite).

We will try to prove the following theorem.

> **Theorem.** Let $R$ be a ring with $1_R$ and $M$ an left $R$-module. The following are equivalent.
>
> 1. $M$ is a left, free $R$-module.
> 2. $M$ has basis.

*Proof.* $1.\implies 2.$ According to our definition, $M=\bigoplus_{i\in I} R_i$, where $R_i:=\langle b_i \rangle \cong _RR,\ \forall i \in I $. 
 and $I$ is a set of indexes (finite or infinite).

We define the set 
$$S:=\{e_i:=(\delta_{i,\lambda} )_{\lambda\in I}: i\in I\}\subseteq \bigoplus_{i\in I}
 R,$$
where $\delta_{i,\lambda} =1_R$, if $\lambda=i$ and $\delta_{i,\lambda} =0_R$ otherwise. Then, it's easy to observe that the set $S$ is $R$-basis for $\bigoplus_{i\in I} R$ has an $R$-basis and $\bigoplus_{i\in I} R_i \cong \bigoplus_{i\in I} R = M $, thus $M$ has an $R$-basis.

$2.\implies 1.$ We suppose that $S:=\{e_i \in M :i \in I \} \subseteq M$ is an $R$-basis for $M$. Obviously, the key is to define an $R$ module homomorphism 
$$\phi:M\longrightarrow \bigoplus_{i\in I} R.$$

And now my questions.

**Questions.**
(1) Is the first part okey?

(2) The index set $I$ may be infinite, so does $S$. Then, does every element $m\in M=\langle S \rangle$ have a unique expression, as finite linear $R$-combination, in the form $m=\sum_{k=1}^{n} r_k e_k$, where $n\in \Bbb N , r_k \in R, e_k \in  S$?

(3) Which the $R$-module isomorphism?

*Thank you.*

Comment: I'm guessing that the definition is using the *internal* direct sum (which is a *relation* between submodules, despite the functional and equality notation) and not the *external* direct sum which has formal elements $\sum_{i \in I} \lambda_i e_i$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yes, indeed. But the two direct sums are in some way equivalent. So, it'doesn't really matter. Do you agree? Note that this definitions is taken form Rotman's book, *Advanced Modern Algebra, AMS, 2012.*

Comment: Well, even when you have a canonical isomorphism $\alpha$, it's usual to make applications of that isomorphism explicit - so instead of $S := \{ e_i \ldots \}$ you would say something like $S := \{ \alpha(e_i) \ldots \}$.  So, under the canonical isomorphism of the external direct sum $\bigoplus_{i\in I} R$ with $R$ under the hypothesis of $R$ being the internal direct sum of submodules $\langle b_i \rangle \simeq R$, what would $e_i$ be sent to?

Comment: Okay, let's take the external. It's easy then to do the transfromation. But my question is, shall we sent $m:=\sum_{i=1}^{n}r_i e_i \longmapsto \phi(m)= \phi (\sum_{i=1}^{n}r_i e_i) :=(r_1,...,r_n)  $? And should these sums be finite?

Comment: I think maybe I'm not getting my point across: the problem as written mentions no isomorphisms, so the $F = \bigoplus_{i\in I} R_i$ condition could only be referring to the internal direct sum condition, and using the isomorphism to external direct sum could only be an intermediate step in the proof.  And personally, I think going through the external direct sum is an unnecessary complication.  My approach would be: prove that if $F = \bigoplus_{i\in I} R_i$ where $R_i := R b_i$ satisfies $R_i \simeq R$, then $\{ b_i \mid i \in I \}$ is a basis for $F$; and conversely.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Let me please rephrase your consideration. So, you suggest to prove that $M$ is free with $M=\bigoplus_{i\in I} \langle b_i \rangle \iff M$ has a basis $B$ (and this basis is $B:=\{b_i\in M:i\in I\}$). Right?

Comment: I'd say more specifically, my suggestion is to prove $M = \bigoplus_{i\in I} \langle b_i \rangle$ and $\langle b_i \rangle \simeq_R R$ for all $i \in I$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\{ b_i \mid i \in i \}$ is a basis for $M$.  (The part requiring $\langle b_i \rangle \simeq_R R$ is essential to rule out modules like $R / I$ where $I$ is a proper nontrivial ideal.)

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's much more better like this. Will there have a big difference or will we loose rigourousness if we take elements $\{b_1,...,b_m\}$ instead of the indexed family $\{b_i:i\in I\}$? It's a mess with it...

Comment: Is my question so bad? Why no comments or answers?